# Localization With Database MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I am working on a multilingual ASP.NET MVC application (MVC4).

I want to make my resource file strings to be editable at runtime without recompiling the application and without app pool recycling And it doesn't look possible with `.resx` file, so I migrate to store string resources in Database.

I have to Get Each Label/String Resource From Database, so there will be **more hits to database** for each request. **How to fix that?**

I have googled around and someone suggests to load the resource in a dictionary and store it as application variable, at login/Sign In page and use that dictionary as resource instead of database hit.

I am confused, what will be effective approach.Can someone guide me in right direction to **avoid more database hits?**

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same concerns using .resx files for localization. They just did not work well when the persons doing the translation were not programmers. Now, we have a translation page in our admin area. Works great.

One area which we still don't have a good solution for are the data annotations, which still use the .resx files. I have trimmed the source below to remove any references to our actual database structures or tables.

There is a fallback to using the underlying .resx file, if an entry does not exist in the database. If there is not an entry in the .resx file, I split the word whenever a capitol letter is found ( CamelSpace is a string extension method ).

Lastly, depending on your implementation, you may need to remove the context caching, especially if you are caching out of process.

A few examples of usage:

```
@LanguageDb.Translate("Enter your first name below","FirstNamePrompt")

@LanguageDb.Me.FirstName

@String
    .Format(LanguageDb
                .Translate(@"You can be insured for 
                      {0} down and {1} payments of {2}"),
            Model.Down,Model.NumPayments,
            Model.InstallmentAmount)



public class LanguageDb : DynamicObject
{
    public static dynamic Me = new LanguageDb();
    private LanguageDb() { }

    public static string Translate(string englishPhrase, string resourceCode = null)
    {
        return GetTranslation(englishPhrase, resourceCode) ?? englishPhrase;
    }
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = GetTranslation(binder.Name);
        return true;
    }

    private static string GetTranslation(string resourceName, string resourceCode = null)
    {
        resourceCode = resourceCode ?? resourceName;
        if (resourceCode.Contains(" ") || resourceCode.Length > 50)
        {
            resourceCode = resourceName.GetHashCode().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        var lang = (string)HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] ?? "en";

        // cache entries for an hour
        var result = Get(subagent + "_" + lang + "_" + resourceCode, 3600, () =>
        {
            // cache a datacontext object for 30 seconds.
            var context = Get("_context", 30, () => new YourDataContext()) as YourDataContext;
            var translation = context.Translations.FirstOrDefault(row => row.lang == lang && row.Code == resourceCode);
            if (translation == null)
            {
                translation = new Lookup { 
                    Code = resourceCode, 
                    lang = lang, 
                    Value = Language.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName, Language.Culture) 
                                    ?? resourceName.CamelSpace() 
                };
                context.Translations.Add(translation);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return translation.Value;
        });

        return result;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        // ignore this
        return true;
    }

    public static T Get<T>(string cacheId, int secondsToCache, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {
        T item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheId) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            if (secondsToCache > 0)
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
                    cacheId, item, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                    new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsToCache), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheId, item);
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```